# How to create a fault tolerant kafka worker that processes data without using Kafka Streams?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using python and Kafka.
My data have to be partitioned by customer and processed in a time window fashion.
This part is relative straight-forward even without using Kafka streams.

However implementing a fault tolerant mechanism without using Kafka Streams seems to be more difficult. This is what I have implemented so far.

After processing an event, the worker publishes the processed event on a "restore" topic. When a worker goes down, after the rebalancing procedure, each worker reads all the processed events from the restore topic. If the key of the processed event does not belong to the partitions which have been assigned to the worker after the rebalance, the worker just skips it.
In order to ensure that all the workers read all the processed event at least once, the auto commit is disabled.

This solution seems to work but the obvious downside is that all the workers need to read all the processed event from the restore topic.

I would like to know if there's a better and easy enough solution without using Kafka Streams. Thank you very much!